# NameError in RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Just installed Devise yesterday, the SIGN-IN function is working just fine i.e: If I type in an incorrect password/username it'll have a flash MSG, I can login with the correct info and so on...

However, the SiGN-UP area isn't quite the same. When I type in wrong login credentials I get the following error:

### NameError in RegistrationsController#create

#### undefined local variable or method `authentications' for #

Not sure which other controllers or contents to include so as soon as you ask, i'll update the OP with them.

**User.rb Controller**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentication

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
    authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])

  end

  def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
  end
end
```

***Authentications Controller***

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

***Full Trace***

```
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
app/models/user.rb:19:in `password_required?'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__3532959459969647100__validate__3266504065108489171__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/validations.rb:228:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3532959459969647100__validation__3266504065108489171__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/validations.rb:195:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
devise (2.2.3) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__4484154356758125938__process_action__1943485731429773152__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__499975101759753584__call__3266504065108489171__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: `app/models/user.rb:19:in 'password_required?'` what is implemented there?

Comment: @MrYoshiji i've added the User.rb file to the op.

Comment: Ah, I see where is the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted it! (I hope so)

```
has_many :authentication
```

Should be:

```
has_many :authentications
```

Why? Because Rails expects you to pluralize the name of the object for the has_many and other cases.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! @MrYoshiji 's answer was the proper fix.